# using filename in vlookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to find a non-vba solution for getting a value via vlookup. The vlookup should use the sheet name as the search criteria. The sheet name format is "00000"

```
=VLOOKUP(N1;[otherfilename.xlsx]othersheetname!$A$3:$C$10000;3;false)
```

when writing "12345" into Cell N1 it work perfectly fine
when writing in Cell N1:

```
=MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("[",CELL("filename",A1))+1,FIND("]", CELL
("filename",A1))-FIND("[",CELL("filename",A1))-6)
```

the Cell returns also "12345" but VLOOKUP does not work anymore.

Why is this different to straight putting a value into the Cell?
How do I solve this?

Solution:
Wrapping VALUE() around MID()

Comment: Try wrapping `VALUE()` around `MID(...)`. The text representation of `"12345"` isn't the same as the numeric value `12345` and `VLOOKUP` is sensitive to the difference.

Comment: Check if one of them is treated as a number (as opposed to text string consisting of numbers)

Comment: Thanks Peter! VALUE() around MID() solved the problem!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to reference the location that is generated from string you should use `INDIRECT()` like this:

```
=INDIRECT("[otherfilename.xlsx]othersheetname!$A$3:$C$10000")
```

This will return values from the range in desired sheets.